# Log4J doesn`t write to file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

In my application I want to log to file and console. I use the logger in my classed:

```
 private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLASSNAME);
```

The configuration file is loaded as intended (see `setfile` line in output) with:

```
  DOMConfigurator.configure("c:\\test\\log4j2.xml");
```

output:

```
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Level value for root is  [DEBUG].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender]
log4j: Setting property [append] to [false].
log4j: Setting property [maxFileSize] to [10MB].
log4j: Setting property [maxBackupIndex] to [10].
log4j: Setting property [file] to [c:\test\App.log].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: setFile called: c:\test\App.log, false
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Adding appender named [file] to category [root].
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p     %c{1}:%L - %m%n].
log4j: Adding appender named [console] to category [root].
```

but when I try to log directly after the entry above I won`t get any result

```
  LOGGER.logp(Level.ALL, CLASSNAME, "TEST", "TEST__");
```

The programm is allowed to write the file.
Console output does work, regardless of loading the file or not.

Does anyone spot may error?

Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"  xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
          value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="false" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="file" value="c:\\test\\App.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Edit: I use log4j-1.2.17

Edit2: Turns out the mailer component can log in the file while above code still results only in logging in the console window...

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Mailer.class);

  public static void logMail(String mailString)
  {
    log.error(mailString);
    log.info(mailString);
  }
```

Comment: Which version of log4j are u using?

Comment: Could you try changing append value to true?

Comment: damn.. I created the file to check security settings but forgot that appening is not allowed.. shame on me.. Post that as an answer and I´ll accept that.. thx a lot!

Comment: I think append=false will override the last line..but it should still write to file...

Comment: BTW.... LOGGER.logp(Level.ALL, CLASSNAME, "TEST", "TEST__");    I am not able to compile this line in the version you mentioned.

Comment: Hehe.. @MarcWittmann, it's easy to overlook. I'll add it as an answer :)

Comment: ah well, yes, it still doen`t log properly.. problem not solved.. the loging is from  Mailer.logMail(""); which is the logging component of the Mailer class... this component can log - log4j still cannot :/

Comment: @sumit gupta   you`re correct, they say (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-jul/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/jul/ApiLogger.html) it`s a log4j 2.x function but I refer (checked the project) to log4j 1.2.17 and use it that way.. I´m confused

Comment: `private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass()); 
logger.info("hello world");` Does this work?

Does this work?

Comment: Doesn`t work.. "hello world" output is only in console window 
Strangely the mailer component logs in the defined location but not log4J

Comment: You are using ApiLogger that is part of log4j 2.0 log4j-jul project. And you are loading log4j.xml file using DOMConfigurator file which is from log4j 1.2.17. I think, you need to move to log4j 2.0 and load configuration in that way. Version mismatch is creating the problem.

Comment: You`re right, in the project I had to add a component three different logging approaches were made... java logging (java.util.logging) and two versions of Log4J Logging.. after I realized some components were in fact logging and some not I will redesign the application with a proper log4j 2.0 Logging.. thx a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically you are trying to use jdk logging with log4j implementation. For that you need to use > log4j 2.0 . And use log4j-jul adapter to route all calls made to jdk logging api to log4j2.

You can try as below..
Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Sample Class File

```
package com.test.log4j_test;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class App 
{

    private static final String CLASSNAME = "App.class";
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CLASSNAME);

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException,    IOException
    {
        LOGGER.logp(Level.WARNING, CLASSNAME, "TEST", "TEST__");
    }
}
```

log4j.xml File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Configuration>
      <Appenders>
        <File name="A1" fileName="c:\\test\\app.log" append="true">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
          <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
      </Appenders>
      <Loggers>
        <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="debug">
          <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="ALL">
          <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
          <AppenderRef ref="A1"/>
        </Root>
      </Loggers>
    </Configuration>
```

And to run this program, add below java property

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///c:/test/log4.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

If the file exists and you have append = false it won't be able to log to that file.

```
<param name="append" value="false" />
```

Change this line to true, or delete the file should fix your problem with nothing being written to file.

Comment: Helped me to find the real problems.. after I switched that on at least some components worked.
And since 3 logging components have the same class name and were used over various versions of the application the mix created this behaviour.. (see solution above) thx a lot crea1